# Estado HTTP 500 – Internal Server Error, Netbeans ide 13 tomcat 8.5.78

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

I am doing a login with servlet but I get this error:

I don't know if it's a tomcat problem or why it will be but I already tried with netbeans 13 and netbeans 8.2 and jdk 18, jdk 8 and I still get the same error

The connection works correctly because I already checked it with a code

*The mistake is:*
Type: Status Report

Description: The requested resource is not available.

sometimes i get this too

exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class [controlador.Validar]
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:367)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:639)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:882)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1647)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: controlador.Validar
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1420)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1228)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:367)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:639)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:882)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1647)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

note The full trace of the cause of this error is in the server log files.

index.jsp

````
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container center-block" >
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="logo.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
                <form method="POST" action="Validar">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>No de Documento</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtusuario">
                        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Ingrese su documento sin espacios ni puntos</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Contraseña</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" name="txtpassword">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group form-check">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Permanecer loggeado</label>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="accion" value="Ingresar">Ingresar</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
              </div>  
            </div>
 
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>```

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Controlador.java

/*
 Servlet Controlador
 */
package Controlador;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet(name = "Controlador", urlPatterns = {"/Controlador"})
public class Controlador extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String menu = request.getParameter("menu");
        //Redirecciona a las paginas según la opción seleccionada agregando los casos respectivos
        if(menu.equals("Principal")){
             request.getRequestDispatcher("Principal.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
        if(menu.equals("Productos")){
            request.getRequestDispatcher("Productos.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
        if(menu.equals("Empleados")){
            request.getRequestDispatcher("Empleados.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
        if(menu.equals("Clientes")){
            request.getRequestDispatcher("Clientes.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
        if(menu.equals("Ventas")){
            request.getRequestDispatcher("Ventas.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
validar.java
/*
 Servlet Validar
 */
package controlador;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import Modelo.Usuario;
import Modelo.UsuarioDAO;


@WebServlet(name = "Validar", urlPatterns = {"/Validar"})
public class Validar extends HttpServlet {

    Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
    UsuarioDAO usuarioDAO = new UsuarioDAO();

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet Validar</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet Validar at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
       

        String accion = request.getParameter("accion");
        if (accion.equalsIgnoreCase("Ingresar")) {
            int documento = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txtusuario"));
            String pass = request.getParameter("txtpassword");
            try {
                usuario = usuarioDAO.Validar(documento, pass);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Validar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            if (usuario.getNombre() != null) {
                request.setAttribute("usuario", usuario);
                request.getRequestDispatcher("Controlador?menu=Principal").forward(request, response);
            } else {
                request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }

        } else {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

} 

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
usuario.java
package Modelo;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Usuario {
    
    int id;
    int documento;
    String nombre, correo, estado, password, rol;

    public Usuario() {
    }

    public String getRol() {
        return rol;
    }

    public void setRol(String rol) {
        this.rol = rol;
    }

    public Usuario(int id, int documento, String nombre, String correo, String estado, String password, String rol) {
        this.id = id;
        this.documento = documento;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.correo = correo;
        this.estado = estado;
        this.password = password;
        this.rol = rol;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getDocumento() {
        return documento;
    }

    public void setDocumento(int documento) {
        this.documento = documento;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getCorreo() {
        return correo;
    }

    public void setCorreo(String correo) {
        this.correo = correo;
    }

    public String getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(String estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
UsuarioDAO.java
package Modelo;

import Config.Conexion;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class UsuarioDAO {

    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs;
    Conexion cn = new Conexion();
      
   public Usuario Validar(int documento, String password) throws SQLException {
        Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
        String consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE documento = ? AND password = ?";
        con = cn.Conexion();
        try {
            ps = con.prepareStatement(consulta);
            ps.setInt(1, documento);
            ps.setString(2, password);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            rs.next();
            do {
                usuario.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                usuario.setDocumento(rs.getInt("documento"));
                usuario.setNombre(rs.getString("nombre"));
                usuario.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
                usuario.setCorreo(rs.getString("correo"));
                usuario.setEstado(rs.getString("estado"));
                usuario.setRol(rs.getString("rol"));
            } while (rs.next());
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UsuarioDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        return usuario;

    }
}

`
````

Comment: ready, excuse me

Comment: I think you already have all the necessary information.